# GitHub Action: Invalid environment variable format

Tags: json, typescript, bash, github, github-actions

I have a problem with Github action. After I configured `README.md` over web browser after that GitHub action throw error:

```
Run export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
  export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
  echo "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Invalid environment variable format 'Indicate that a variable can have the value `null`. Null-Safety is default from version **2.12.0** in the Dart language.'
```

The variable format is a text from the `README.md` and now no matter how I edit it always throws an error with the old error text. I tried to google it but not found any similar solution.

- Current mine variable format

> Null-Safety is enabled as default and it will indicate that a variable may have the value null. Required in the new Dart language from version 2.12.0.

My workflow file:

```
name: release master branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: install vsce
        run: sudo npm install -g vsce
      - name: extract version number
        run: |
          export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
          echo "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: package the extension
        run: vsce package
      - name: release package to github repo
        uses: marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest
        with:
          repo_token: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          automatic_release_tag: master-v${{ env.BUILD_VERSION }}
          prerelease: true
          title: 'Json to Dart Extension master-v${{ env.BUILD_VERSION }}'
          files: |
            ./json-to-dart-${{ env.BUILD_VERSION }}.vsix
```

By adding paths ignore do not resolve it.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths-ignore:
      - '**/README.md'
```

The full code is public; you can find it at https://github.com/hiranthaR/Json-to-Dart-Model

Partial log:

```
...
2021-08-02T19:38:38.3085331Z ##[group]Run sudo npm install -g vsce
2021-08-02T19:38:38.3086141Z [36;1msudo npm install -g vsce[0m
2021-08-02T19:38:38.3129504Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2021-08-02T19:38:38.3129978Z ##[endgroup]
2021-08-02T19:38:42.3974877Z /usr/local/bin/vsce -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vsce/out/vsce
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4134841Z + vsce@1.96.1
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4135550Z added 73 packages from 42 contributors in 3.582s
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4443780Z ##[group]Run export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4444834Z [36;1mexport BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')[0m
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4445782Z [36;1mecho "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV[0m
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4489050Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4489590Z ##[endgroup]
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4690016Z ##[error]Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4703378Z ##[error]Invalid environment variable format 'Indicate that a variable can have the value `null`. Null-Safety is default from version **2.12.0** in the Dart language.'
2021-08-02T19:38:42.4890985Z Post job cleanup.
...
```

Comment: As an aside, `export` makes the variable visible to _children_ of the shell. Your shell has no children, so the `export` is not doing anything useful.

Comment: Please add debugging details: What's in your `package.json`?

Comment: Added raw log data

Comment: It's still not clear what `README.md` or Markdown have with any of this to do, or what _"configured `README.md` over web browser"_ is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to your `README.md` in any way. Instead, the issue is that your `package.json` contains these other strings which include the literal string `version`. You are adding all these lines to your `$GITHUB_ENV` file, and all except the first are syntax errors.

```
BUILD_VERSION=3.2.8
Indicate that a variable can have the value `null`. Null-Safety is default from version **2.12.0** in the Dart language.
Disable ask for confirmation to start the conversion from the file `models.jsonc`.
Default target directory when conversion is from the file `models.jsonc`.
```

Try a more specific regular expression, or, as already suggested in a comment, use Awk to do the filtering, which allows for more precision.  This also gets rid of the [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

```yaml
      - name: extract version number
        run: |
          BUILD_VERSION=$(awk -F \" '$2 == "version" {print $4}' package.json)
          echo "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In fact, you can do this in a single line; clearly, the indirection via a temporary variable wasn't helping you debug this anyway (though adding `set -x` to the shell script snippet probably would have).

```yaml
      - name: extract version number
        run:
          awk -F \" '$2 == "version" {print "BUILD_VERSION=" $4}' package.json >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Properly speaking, you should probably use a JSON-aware tool like `jq` to extract the version number and nothing else.

```yaml
      - name: extract version number
        run:
          jq -r '"BUILD_VERSION=\(.version)"' package.json >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to deal with this is documented in the Github Actions documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings

Instead of doing

```bash
  export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
  echo "BUILD_VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

You use the multiline string format as described in the documentation with

```
{name}<<{delimiter}
{value}
{delimiter}
```

```bash
  export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
  echo "BUILD_VERSION<<EOFMARKER" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
  echo "${BUILD_VERSION}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
  echo "EOFMARKER" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
```

Note: you should take care to read the security warning about using a constant like `EOF` as a delimiter here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections, so if you take input that you consider "from the user" you can use something to generate random data as a delimiter like this:

```bash
  export BUILD_VERSION=$(grep version package.json | awk -F \" '{print $4}')
  delimiter="$(openssl rand -hex 8)"
  echo "BUILD_VERSION<<${delimiter}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
  echo "${BUILD_VERSION}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
  echo "${delimiter}" >> ${GITHUB_ENV}
```